# Set of vectors spanning $\mathbb{R}^k$: does it exist $i\in \{1,...,I-1,I+1,...,n\}$ such that $(x_i-x_I)'\beta=0\Leftrightarrow \beta=0_k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

Consider a set of vectors of dimension $k\times 1$ $$x_1,..., x_I,...,x_n$$ Suppose that the set of vectors $$x_1-x_I,..., x_{I-1}-x_I, x_{I+1}-x_I,..., x_n-x_I$$ spans $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Question: consider $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^k$. Does it exist $i\in \{1,...,I-1,I+1,...,n\}$ such that $(x_i-x_I)'\beta=0\Leftrightarrow \beta=0_k$? ($0_k$ is a vector of zeros of dimension $k \times 1$)

My thoughts: the fact that we have $x_1-x_I,..., x_{I-1}-x_I, x_{I+1}-x_I,..., x_n-x_I$ spanning $\mathbb{R}^k$ implies that there should be a non-zero vector $(x_i-x_I)$. However, I am confused by the fact that some elements of it could be zero. If that is the case, how can I guarantee that 
 $(x_i-x_I)'\beta=0\Leftrightarrow \beta=0_k$?

Comment: What is $(x_i - x_I)'$?

Comment: It is one of the vectors among $x_1-x_I,..., x_{I-1}-x_I, x_{I+1}-x_I,..., x_n - x_I$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot guarantee the existence of such an index $i$ in general. Here is an example:

Set $k=3$.

Take $x_{1}=(1,0,1)$, $x_{2}=(1,1,0)$, $x_{3}=(0,1,1)$ and $x_{4}=(0,0,0)$. Set $I=4$

Then $x_{i}-x_{I}=x_{i}$ and $\{ x_{i} : i=1,2,3 \}$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

For $x_{1}$, take $\beta =(-1,0,1)$

For $x_{2}$, take $\beta =(1,-1,0)$

For $x_{3}$, take $\beta =(0,-1,1)$

Comment: Thank you. I see your point. To be sure I understood, suppose instead that we know that $(x_i-x_I)'\beta=0$ $\forall i \neq I$. Would that imply $\beta=0_k$ from the spanning condition?

Comment: Yes. The spanning condition implies the existence of a set of k linearly independent vectors. Beta has to be orthogonal to all of them (this is, beta is a vector in a othogonal subspace to the directions of each of those linearly independent vectors). The only subspace which is orthogonal to the k directions of the k-dimensional space is the zero. Hence, beta has to be zero.